# What is a typical Gearman flow for database modification?

Tags: php, gearman

Would appreciate some help understanding typical best practices in carrying out a series of tasks using Gearman in conjunction with PHP (among other things).

Here is the basic scenario:

A user uploads a set of image files through a web-based interface. The php code responding to the POST request generates an entry in a database for each file, mostly with null entries in the columns, queues a job for each to do analysis using Gearman, generates a status page and exits.

The Gearman worker gets a job for a file and starts a relatively long-running analysis. The result of that analysis is a set of parameters that need to be inserted back into the database record for that file.

My question is, what is the generally accepted method of doing this? Should I use a callback that will ultimately kick off a different php script that is going to do the modification, or should the worker function itself do the database modification?

Everything is currently running on the same machine; I'm planning on using Gearman for background scheduling, rather than for scaling by farming out to different machines, but in any case any of the functions could connect to the database wherever it is.

Any thoughts appreciated; just looking for some insights on how this typically gets structured and what might be considered best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to use Gearman?  I only ask because it was the defacto PHP job server about 15 years ago but hasn't been a reliable solution for quite some time.  I am not sure if things have drastically improved in the last 12 months, but last time I evaluated Gearman, it wasn't production capable.

Now, on to the questions.

> what is the generally accepted method of doing this? Should I use a callback that will ultimately kick off a different php script that is going to do the modification, or should the worker function itself do the database modification?

You are going to follow this general pattern with any job queue:

- Collect a unit of work.  In your case, it will be 1 of the images and any information about who that image belongs to, user id, etc.
- Submit the work to the job queue with this information.
- Job Queue's worker process picks up the work, and starts processing it.  This is where I would create records in the database as you can opt to not create them on job failure.

The job queue is going to track which jobs have completed and usually the status of completion.  If you are using gearman, this is the gearmand process.  You also need something pickup work and process that work, I will refer to this as the job worker.  The job worker is where the concurrency happens which is what i think you were referring to when you said "kick off a different php script."  You can just kick off a PHP script at an interval (with supervisord or a cronjob) for a kind of poll & fork approach.  It's not the most efficient approach, but it doesn't sound like it will really matter for your applications use case.  You could also use pcntl_fork or pthreads in PHP to get more control over your concurrent processes and implement a worker pool pattern, but it is much more complicated than just firing off a script.  If you are interested in trying to implement some concurrency in PHP, I have a proof-of-concept job worker for beanstalkd available on GitHub that implements a worker pool with both fork and pthreads.  I have also include a couple of other resources on the subject of concurrency.

- [Job Worker (pthreads)](https://github.com/kwhat/legume)
- [Job Worker (fork)](https://github.com/kwhat/legume/tree/pcntl)
- [PHP Daemon Example](https://github.com/lifo101/php-daemon)
- [PHP IPC Example](https://github.com/lifo101/php-ipc)

Comment: Gearman first stable release was in 2009 and is very capable and reliable job server software. When configured with persistence, it can withstand outages and server crashes without losing jobs. It's perfect for doing image analysis and processing.

Comment: Last time I tested it about a year ago, the daemon was deadlocking randomly under heavy load when using a long running PHP process.  Sure Gearman is pretty reliable if you kill it after every job, but the fact that wired things start happening when the process is long lived suggests that it is not production stable by my standards.  Your millage may very.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - much appreciated. I'm not exactly wedded to the idea of using Gearman, just trying to avoid reinventing the wheel; thanks for all of the other suggestions, I will go and check all of those out. The issue I'm really trying to understand first is where the database update should happen; the calling php code (that the user is interacting with) has all of the context, since it's part of a session involving a logged-in user, but anything after that is going to be starting from scratch. I guess that means that the worker is going to do the database update...

Comment: ...I was thinking about the security implications of that. I haven't seen a discussion of this anywhere, but presumably there is some configuration in gearmand that locks down the source of job requests?

Comment: just to clarify, when I said "kick off a different php script" I was actually thinking of a third script triggered in response to a callback from the worker on completion. Assuming the worker is also php (probably yes) I'm envisaging either 2 or 3 php scripts; one that is the main web serving process, the worker, and then... maybe something else that updates the database on activation of the callback by the worker, or alternatively the worker just does the update itself.

Comment: additional clarification: based on comments elsewhere, I'm assuming that the php worker script will need to be designed to run for a period of time and then cleanly exit. I'll then register that script with supervisord to keep it running indefinitely. Does that sound sensible?

Comment: @DMK, I have had very good results with beanstalkd as a direct Gearman replacement, but make a choose that best fits your needs as each job queue will offer a different set of features.  Q: "where the database update should happen" A: where it makes sense for your workflow.  What you go on to describe is breaking out the work from the user context into a unit of work. Just think about the things you need to complete that unit, and pass that info as the unit. The job worker will receive that unit and apply a "job" (aka your code) to the unit of work.

Comment: That job will probably need to update the database if it succeeds, that's totally ok. Try to avoid things like doing an insert before the job runs that would need to be deleted if the job does not complete.  Going back and trying to cleanup the aysnc process after you have let go of it is going to require more code further complicating the process.  As far as security, the interface that the job queue accepts jobs on should be behind the firewall.  The normal security practices apply to the client and the job. (prepared statements, escaping user input, etc)

Comment: Q: "need to be designed to run for a period of time."  Not really, again depends on your needs. Generally the job worker is going to poll for jobs.  Is the overhead of starting a new php script going to effect your performance for the desired volume of work?  Basically if you are not shooting for 1000's of jobs a second, this is not an issue for you.  supervisord or crond can be used to just pound out new PHP processes.  If there is no work, it just exits.  If there is work, it does the next one, then exists.  You start as many as you need to at some interval and no cap.

Comment: Many thanks for the additional comments - very helpful. I'll go work on some solutions now... ;-)